# How to validate a RSA public and private key pair in Python

Tags: python, rsa, pycryptodome

I generated an RSA public and private key pair using the `pycryptodome` module and returned the private key to the user. Now, for fetching some specific data, I need to validate the public and private key pair. I have both of them in `bytes` form:

```py
public_key = b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlisb129W98LyU3caYcTr\nowqPJLUuaP9imnAOcJxzrKgK..........................qGUPMhPxVFA92mifqr9T2m5cI5/b\nCwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

private_key = bytes(input())
```

I need to create a function to check whether the private key entered by the user matches the public key stored by the program.

Comment: You could import private and public key and then compare modulus and public exponent of both. If both match, both keys match. Apart from that: Why do you create the private key for the user? The user's private key should only be known by the user.

Comment: @Topaco thank you, I'll try that! also I was just making some dummy projects for college work and thought of using RSA but got stuck here, so wanted to know how to proceed :)

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem? I am also looking for an answer to your question.